# How to use custom tokens with flex ant tasks

Tags: apache-flex, mxmlc

I am trying to use the flex ant task to build my Flex project.
Before using ant, I ran the mxmlc command like this:

```
mxmlc -load-config mxmlc_conf.xml src\project.mxml -output bin-debug +libs=<absolute_path_to>3rdparty\libs +<other_token>=<absoulte_path_to_value>
```

The thing is now I am supposed to use flex ant tasks and it looks like they disabled (or forgot about) the custom tokens like += as I haven't found a way to pass those to the mxmlc task.

I have tried using:

> < mxmlc ...>< arg token value="..." />< /mxmlc>

but that doesn't work.

What I am trying to accomplish is to get rid of hard-coded paths in the mxmlc config-file (mxmlc_conf.xml) and at first I used the custom tokens in mxmlc but now I don't know how to pass paths as variables to the config file.

I can accept suggestions.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do the exact same thing (replace hard-coded paths in the config file) and I'm looking for the same solution.

It seems we might have to abandon the mxmlc task and simply use mxmlc from the command line:

```
<exec searchpath="true" executable="amxmlc"
        dir="${project.build.outputDirectory}">
        <env key="PATH"
            path="${env.PATH}:/Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.5/sdks/4.5.1/bin" />
        <arg value="-load-config" />
        <arg value="../src/main/resources/dumpConfig.xml" />
        <arg value="+libs=/absolute/path/to/3rd/party/libs" /> 
        <arg value="-output" />
        <arg
            value="${project.build.outputDirectory}/${application.name}.swf" />
        <arg value="../src/main/flex/${application.name}.mxml" />
    </exec>
```

Something like this should work.  I'm just hoping there's a better way (that is, a way we can actually use the mxml ant target!)

I hope that helps someone...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<target>
    <replace file="mxmlc_conf.xml" token="$${libs}" value="absolute/path/to/3rdparty/libs"/>
    <mxmlc ...>
        <load-config filename="mxmlc_conf.xml" />
    </mxmlc>
    <replace file="mxmlc_conf.xml" token="absolute/path/to/3rdparty/libs" value="$${libs}"/>
</target>
```